# Receive SMS from Twilio

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api

I am creating a program that asks the user something like "How are you doing today":

```
    Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

    Message message = Message.creator(new PhoneNumber("+000000"), // To
                                                                        // number
            new PhoneNumber("0000000"), // From number
            "How are you doing today?" // SMS body
    ).create();

    System.out.println(message.getSid());
```

And then then the program will listen for whatever response the user texts back from their phone.

Now, Twilio says this about receiving SMS:

> You can associate that phone number with an SMS URL. When someone sends a text message to that phone number, Twilio makes an HTTP request to your URL with the body of the message and the sender's phone number. You can then respond to the SMS by returning a reply message in the HTTP response to Twilio.

Now, I understand that when the user texts back, Twilio makes an HTTP request to my program, like so:

[image]

However, in the tutorial, they create an HTTP tunnel using ngrok to allow the HTTP request to go through. **My application is supposed to be able to run in anyone's computer without prior configuration**. How would you recommend I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid that without exposing your application to the Net you won't be able to use that particular API.

What you can try to do instead is polling / fetching:

> When you send an SMS or MMS message via the REST API, using the
>   [`<Message>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/message) verb in TwiML, or someone sends a message to one of your
>   Twilio numbers Twilio creates a [Message instance resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#instance). The
>   [Messages list resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#list) represents the set of messages sent from and
>   received by an account.
>
> Retrieving sent and received messages from history can be achieved by
>   querying the [Messages list resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#list).

A short example to start with is available [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-retrieve-and-modify-message-history-in-java#search-previous-messages).